# Getting the URL parameter in Go issue

Tags: go

I have a URL that looks something like this: http://localhost/templates/verify?key=ijio

My router looks like this:

```
import (
"github.com/gorilla/mux"
"github.com/justinas/alice"
)

ctx := &model.AppContext{db, cfg} // passes in database and config
verifyUser := controller.Verify(ctx)
mx.Handle("/verify", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(verifyUser)).Methods("GET").Name("verify")
```

I want to get the key parameter out of the URL, so I use the following code:

```
func Verify(c *model.AppContext) http.HandlerFunc {
    fn := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    key := r.URL.Query().Get("key") // gets the hash value that was placed in the URL
    log.Println(key) // empty key
    log.Println(r.URL.Query()) // returns map[]
    // code that does something with key and sends back JSON response
   }
}
```

I used AngularJS to get the JSON data:

```
app.controller("verifyControl", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.message = "";
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: "/verify"
    }).success(function(data) {
         $scope.message = data.msg; // JSON response 
   });

  }]);
```

However, I end up with an empty key variable when I try to print it out. I recently used nginx to take out my .html extension if that's a possible cause of this problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: If you haven't logged/printed the value of `Query` I recommend doing it. Get is pretty straightforwad and your use of it is correct. https://play.golang.org/p/i4kKCUFoiq

Comment: Is r by any chance an http.Request? If so you should probably be calling r.ParseForm() and then using r.Form.Get("key").

Comment: @DmitriGoldring  Yes, r is a request and I tried ParseForm() and it still didn't work.

Comment: Did you check the error returned by ParseForm? Also if this is a POST/PUT/PATCH that contains 'key' as a body parameter you could be overriding your query parameter.

Comment: Please post the code that is necessary to reproduce the issue. Without it it is very hard to say what works incorrectly.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring r.ParseForm() does not seem to return any errors.

Comment: Does Angular add the `key` query parameter?

Comment: @DmitriGoldring No, it just gets the /verify URL and gets the JSON response from it.

Comment: So then how does the `key` parameter end up in the URL that your application receives? It looks like `$http` can take a `params` map that can be used to add GET query parameters.

Comment: @DmitriGoldring An e-mail is sent to the user which contains the link with the `key` parameter. The code is used to verify a user's e-mail address.

Comment: @dtrinh100 Could you please post how the email looks like and what is the browser address bar after you clicking on the link in email. Does it contains  `?key=ijio`?

Comment: @AlexAtNet It simply says to click on the link to verify. The URL in the browser looks like what was posted except the `key` changes based on a generated hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question involves inspecting the request URL link by

```
log.Print(r.URL) // This returns "/verify"
```

However, that's not exactly what you want. Instead, you want the full URL. You can do the following to get the full URL and extract the parameter from it:

```
urlStr := r.Referer()             // gets the full URL as a string
urlFull, err := url.Parse(urlStr) // returns a *URL object
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
    return
}
key := urlFull.Query().Get("key") // now we get the key parameter from the URL
log.Println("Key: " + key) // now you'll get a non empty string
```